# /etc/fstab for my usb drive won't boot

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, usb-drive, disk, fdisk

I've used `sudo blkid` to mount my drive with fstab like this on `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=1169dd89-29fe-436c-9aef-fa78ea7ee138 /media/hd ext4 defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0
```

I also tried

```
PARTUUID=df63cda7-01  /media/hd ext4 defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0
```

However my raspberry pi won't boot. I also formatted the system to ext4 before getting the uuid. It enters emergency mode when booting and asks me to type `journalctl -xb`

I now added the `nofail` option so it'll boot at least, so I don't have to keep editing my SD card:

```
PARTUUID=df63cda7-01  /media/hd ext4 defaults,auto,nofail,umask=000,users,rw 0 0
```

What is going wrong?

When I boot, I cannot see `/dev/sda1` on `df -h` but it appears on `sudo blkid`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo file -sL /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=1169dd89-29fe-436c-9aef-fa78ea7ee138 (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
```

This is dmesg-w when I reconnect the drive

```
[ 1156.384704] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1156.399483] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1156.399843] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1165.388431] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 1165.600753] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a
[ 1165.600776] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1165.600787] usb 1-1.2: Product: Expansion
[ 1165.600796] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 1165.600806] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: NA8Z9LSP
[ 1165.606573] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1165.629063] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 1166.650056] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0708 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1166.657494] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 1167.877041] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 1167.877944] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 1167.877969] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 00 08
[ 1167.889766] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1167.936469]  sda: sda1
[ 1167.944243] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1168.710434] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "umask=000" or missing value
```

This is my `lsusb`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. When you plug-in the USB drive, what does `dmesg` show? And `lsusb`?

Comment: @mattia.b89 just updated the question with this info

Comment: Latest *dmesg* 's line should foresee you the issue

Comment: @mattia.b89 which value should I use then? I'm using this one because it's on the raspberry pi's website: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md. I also tried 0000 without success

Comment: not being an expert, try to remove the *charged* part and let we see if it helps...

Comment: @mattia.b89 it worked when I completely removed the umask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `umask` is not a supported option...

Actually it doesn't:
- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/ext4/ext4.rst
- https://superuser.com/a/837270/809353
- https://superuser.com/a/637171/809353